# Storing a Map in a TLS - Thread Safety in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary, thread-local-storage

Basically a map cannot be added/deleted by two different threads concurrently , so it needs to be synchronized.

And i know that the Thread Local Storage concept in c++ is thread safe and can be accessed by many threads.

```
    std::map<int,int> * pTemp= (std::map<int,int> *) TlsGetValue(sTlsIndex);
    if (pTemp== NULL)
    {
        pTemp= new std::map<int,int>;
        TlsSetValue(sTlsIndex, pTemp);
    }
```

If i put the map in TLS and access it from different child threads add/ delete/ modify the map , then should it be synchronized ?

Since TLS is already synchronized and my map is inside that.

Answer (score 4):

> " thread safe and can be accessed by many threads"

You misunderstand Thread Local Storage - it transparently creates distinct objects for each thread so that they can be easily/quickly found by that thread and safely used *despite not being thread-safe*.

If you want multiple threads accessing *the same* map, you should not put it in thread local storage and should use a `std::mutex` or similar synchronisation primitives to control access and updates.

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to grasp the idea of thread-local storage. It does not synchronize access to the same object - instead, it guarantees that every thread will have it's own version of it, so that multiple threads would not access the same object unless they specifically attempt to do so, by, for example, passing a pointer to thread-local object from one thread to another. Barring the very unusual case of passing those pointers, thread unsafety issues should not arise.

It is mostly (I even dare say only) useful in conjunction with static variables. Automatic variables created on stack are thread-safe by definiton, since there is always only one thread using this stack.

Let me clarify with some examples:

```
typedef std::map<int, int> my_map_t;
my_map_t getmap() {
    static my_map_t my_map = { {10, 20}, {30, 40}, {50, 60} };

    return my_map;
}

void func1() {
    getmap()[70] = 80;
}
void func2() {
    getmap()[90] = 100;
}

...
std::thread thr1(func1);
std::thread thr2(func2);
```

In the example above, `func1()` executing in thr1 and `func2()` executing in thr2 will access the same instance of map, and will perform insertions on it (possibly, of course) siumulatenously, leading to undefined behaviour. The state of the single map after this code can not be predicted.

However, if the code of `getmap()` is replaced in a following way:

```
my_map_t getmap() {
    static _Thread_local my_map_t my_map = { {10, 20}, {30, 40}, {50, 60} };

    return my_map;
}
```

Each threads will have it's OWN copy of the map. There will be two instances of the map in the programm, differing in only one element - one will have (in addition to common elements) an pair of (90, 100) in it, and another will have a pair of (70, 80). The state of those two maps is determined, and there is no uncertainty here.

Comment: _"so there will never be access to the same object from multiple threads"_ That isn't guaranteed. One thread could pass the address of its thread-local variable to another thread, which could access it and cause a data race. So TLS makes it harder, but cannot ensure there will _never_ be accesses from multiple threads.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, well, if you are in the hair-splitting mood, yes.

Comment: If you're going to correct the OP's misunderstanding you might as well do it properly, not replace a mistaken belief in synchronisation guarantees with a belief in address space isolation guarantees or anything like that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, by that account, one can hardly describe anything. All simple sentences become generally invalid. For instance, 'use of mutexes guarantee that there will be no more than one thread entering crytical section' is, generally speaking, wrong. Mutexes can be used improperly, or code may simply goto to the crytical section bypassing mutex acquisition. To avoid the need to preface every statement with lengty prologue and epilogue, people often agree on certain context and assume statements are made in this context.

Comment: *"Automatic variables created on stack are thread-safe by definiton, since there is always only one thread using this stack."* - that statement's a bit too strong / misleading; it's quite common for threads to be started up and all handed pointers or references to some automatic variable(s) on the thread creator's stack - synchronisation is needed for access by those spawned threads just as for a global, static or indeed dynamically allocated variable.

Comment: @SergeyA, _"one can hardly describe anything"_ No, just avoid terms like "never" when that is not true for perfectly correct code. It would be simple to rephrase your first paragraph to remove the untrue "never" claims, without resorting to ridiculous hyperbole about all sentences being invalid. You stated something that is provably not true, why are you quibbling about it?

Comment: @JonathanWakely, edited my answer to satisfy your inner lawyer.